# Placing contents from a page, within another page

Tags: content, content-filtering

Is it possible to place the contents of a Joomla menu item within an article?

Here's a little background to what I'm trying to achieve:

I'm currently using a Joomla component, [form2content](http://www.form2content.com/) on my site for reviews of different courses.

Reviews for all courses are in 1 Joomla category.
Specific course review pages have been setup using the 'Filtered Article List'

I'd like to add on the bottom of the courses pages (which is a Joomla article), the reviews specific to those courses.

Ideally (but doesn't look possible) I would create a Module with a 'Filtered Article List' (containing only reviews in the specific course) and add this module to the bottom of the course page.

But as I say this isn't possible.

Comment: You could duplicate the Joomla article module and add some restraints into it. Or see: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/related-article-after-content

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of plugins at the JED that can load a component anywhere you like (inside articles, inside modules etc.).

- **[NoNumber Components Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/components-anywhere)**
   With Components Anywhere you place components anywhere in your site. So you can now place a component inside an article or even within modules.
  The syntax is super simple. Just place this where you want that component to show:

  ```
  {component url/of/the/component}.
  ```
- **[Include Component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/include-component)**
  The syntax is `{component url='' }`. Replace with the url to your component and include `index.php?`

  For example:

  ```
  {component url='index.php?option=com_component&amp;Itemid=73&amp;parameters....' }
  ```

Maybe one of these will help achieving what you're trying to do.